# Python 3D Plot from dictonary values

Tags: python

I do have a script, which creates a dict with XYZ-values. Following dict includes values at x from -2 to 2, with y from 0 to 2.

```
my_dict = {
-2:{0:1,1:1,2:0},
-1:{0:3,1:1,2:0},
 0:{0:6,1:1,2:9},
 1:{0:-2,1:1,2:2},
 2:{0:1,1:1,2:6}}
```

Now, I don't now how to create a 3D plot out of this. I am aware of the matplotlib library,but I am not sure how to generate my Z-Data. I tried to write a function, to get my Z-data in a mesh, but it doesn't work. This is what I got so far:

```
    x = np.arange(-2, 2, 1)
    y = np.arange(0, 2, 1)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = f(X,Y) #HERE, the function f is what I am searching for.

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap='binary')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

Is there any numpy or pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What is ```self.f()``` supposed to do exactly?

Comment: Do you have nay flexibility in how to populate your dictionary. Meaning have you chose the nested dictionary format thinking that would help you plot, or is that something out of your control?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi, my codes runs as a method in a class, so it will call another method in the class. But I removed it, since it has nothing to do with the problem itself.

Comment: @StephenMason I do have full control over the format, since I generate the dictionary by myself. But I have no idea which format would work better in this situation. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
my_dict = {
-2:{0:1,1:1,2:0},
-1:{0:3,1:1,2:0},
 0:{0:6,1:1,2:9},
 1:{0:-2,1:1,2:2},
 2:{0:1,1:1,2:6}}

x = np.arange(-2, 3, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 3, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)


def f(x, y):
    z = np.zeros(X.reshape(-1).shape)  # Create an "empty" tensor that matches the "flattened" meshgrid
    c = 0  # To index over our "z"
    for i in y:
        for j in x:
            z[c] = my_dict[j][i]  # Fill the empty tensor with its corresponding values from the dictionary (depending on x and y)
            c += 1
    z = z.reshape(X.shape)  # Reshape it back to match meshgrid's shape
    return z


Z = f(x, y)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap='binary')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to add X (the meshgrid) to the function, so it is def f(x, y, X).

Comment: @Sam yeah since your method belongs to a class. I believe you could also not add it to the function by using ```global```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get away with accessing the correct value in your dict via:

`Z = mydict[x][y]`

Comment: I already tried this, but that doesn't work, since it throws this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Is that using x and y, or X and Y?